# How to upload a file as a new version to a document library using the object model

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have a webpart that users can upload files to a document library.

a problem appears if a user uploads a file with a name identical to a file name already exists in the library.

in this case I want the new file to be added as a new version to the existing file using the object model not the web services.

how to achieve that ?

thanks

Comment: What problem? Is versioning enabled on the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's the Answer:

```
//byte array holding the contents of the file
byte[] contents = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
file.CheckOut();
                file.SaveBinary(contents);
                file.CheckIn("New version");
```

the trick is in the check in/ check out

thanks

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this via the REST API for sharepoint online?